# What is the easiest, simplest way to select the max of a column from a table using Entity Manager?

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

MySQL

```
select max(PARAM_DATE) from access_param;
```

zf2

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$pp = $em->createQuery("select max(pdate) as date1 from Access\Entity\Param B");
$user2 = $pp->getResult();

$q =$em->createQuery"selectB.pdate,B.userid,B.pdate,B.password,B.uppercase,B.useridspecial,B.number from Access\Entity\Param B where B.pdate='".$user2."' " );
$user1 = $q->getResult();
```

Comment: Seems like the first one?

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 11 near 'pdate) as date1': Error: 'pdate' is not defined.I m getting error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got output ,i think its useful for beginners using Entity Manager

```
$pp = $em->createQuery("select max(B.pdate) as date1 from Access\Entity\Param B");

$user2 = $pp->getResult();

foreach($user2 as $user2) { 
    $pdate=$user2['date1'];
}

$_POST['pdate']=$pdate; 
$q = $em->createQuery("SELECT 
                   B.pdate, B.userid, B.pdate, B.password, 
                   B.uppercase, B.useridspecial, B.number
                   FROM Access\Entity\Param B
                   WHERE B.pdate='".$_POST['pdate']."'");
```